# Starting `pf` Firewall at System Startup

Tags: network, startup, firewall, pfctl

I have a particular machine that I keep buttoned down very tight. Only a few specific ports/protocols are allowed. I have a pretty basic set of rules that work very well.

While working on a different problem, I realized I could add a few more rules and button things down even tighter by specifying specific ports on specific network interfaces. So for example, on one network interface, only access to 80 & 443 are allowed, no mail or vpn access to that interface.

So here is what one of the old rules looked like:

```
pass in quick proto tcp from any to any port { 80 443 } keep state
```

And this is what one of the new rules looks like:

```
pass in quick proto tcp from any to en1 port { 80 443 } keep state
```

The difference is subtle but I'm specifying a specific network interface, not just in to 'any'. This particular server has three connections to the internet.

**The problem is...** **pf** will no longer start up right at boot with these new rules. When I specify the interface, my **pf** startup script fails to start **pf**. And I have to do it manually through the terminal.

At first glance, the problem seems like my script is probably just trying to use network interfaces that aren't up yet. But I'm already waiting for them to come up. Here is my **pf** startup script, it has been working perfectly for years, until this rule change.

```
#!/bin/bash
ipconfig waitall
/sbin/pfctl -e -f /etc/pf.conf
```

With the new rules, nothing gets loaded at system startup when this runs. But if I run the same **pfctl** command once the system is up, it loads the rules and starts the firewall just fine.

I modified my script to save multiple copies of `ifconfig` so I could see how the status of the two interfaces en0 and en1 progress. Before the `ipconfig waitall` command, they are there with no IPs. After the command, they still have no ips and they show up as 'inactive'. Over the next few seconds, the various IPs start to load up. But the two interfaces show up the whole time.

So the easy patch solution would be to just run `ipconfig waitall` followed by `sleep 6` and call it a day. But I'd rather learn exactly what is causing the hangup so I can wait for that exact 'thing' to be ready, instead of leaving the firewall completely open for 6 seconds. It is a high traffic server and gets lots of hack/ddos attempts so every second may count.

Comment: How are you starting pf and your script?

Comment: The three line code above is my script that starts the firewall. That script is triggered by launchd at system startup.

Comment: Did you check that the script actually gets executed? Can you extend the script to catch any errors it’s commands run into and log this?

Comment: @nohillside I did, and it is. And it outputs nothing, no errors, no comments, nada.

Comment: Did you ever manage to find a solution?

Comment: @sunknudsen Sort of a work-around. I specify the IP address instead of the network interface. Thats not the way I preferred doing it but it does work. My server has static IPs so it's effectively the same.

Answer (score 0):

There is a small error within your added rule:

```
pass in quick proto tcp from any to en1 port { 80 443 } keep state
```

the fields after the key `from` and `to` shoud be IP address and port specification, but not an interface name.

To apply your rule explicitly on incoming traffic on interface `en1`, you should write like this, with macro so as to be able to
maintain your PF rules very quickly:

```
ext_if = "en1"

pass in quick on $ext_if proto tcp from any to any port { 80 443 } keep state
```

If you test the loading of your `pf.conf` interactively, `pfctl` should warn you about a syntax error. As a positive side effect this rule will be independant of the
IP address attributed to `en1`, thus you won't have any
kind os synchronization do wait.

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't have to create your own plist to enable the pf firewall on boot **especially** since you're using the default rule set.  You just need to enable it.  This will launch at the "correct time" when all of your interfaces are configured and up.

#### Step 1:  Edit the Apple supplied plist

The file you're looking for is  `/System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist`.

Change the *Disabled* key from "true" to "false".  Here's what it should look like:

```
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Disabled</key>
    <false/>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.apple.pfctl</string>
    <key>WorkingDirectory</key>
    <string>/var/run</string>
    <key>Program</key>
    <string>/sbin/pfctl</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>pfctl</string>
        <string>-f</string>
        <string>/etc/pf.conf</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

#### Step 2:  Load (or reload) the plist with `launchctl`

```
% sudo launchctl load /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/com.apple.pfctl.plist
```

#### Step 3:  Firewall should be enabled upon boot.

---

#### My recommendation...

**You should not expose the Mac (or any server) directly to the Internet but instead, it should be behind a firewall box/appliance!**

Don't get me wrong - I am a huge fan of pf.  You should still enable the pf firewall on the Mac.   However, if what you're saying is correct that even for a couple seconds you get slammed with DDoS attacks, the (Mac) server shouldn't be dealing with them; your firewall should.  In fact, you should have a proper [pfSense firewall](https://www.pfsense.org/) in front of this server.  By having a separate firewall, the Mac will always be protected regardless of its status (i.e. an inadvertent rule change mistakenly opens it up).

You also gain the advantage of being able to run packages like [pfBlocker-NG](https://docs.netgate.com/pfsense/en/latest/packages/pfblocker.html) on the appliance (will drop connections from known bad actors based on black/white lists) giving you a higher level of protection.  Having it on the appliance frees up your Mac from having to handle those processes.

Comment: I feel like you didn't really read the post here. My problem is not "how to I make a launchd script". The problem is a very spacific issue with not being able to start pf immediately at system boot when my rules contain ethernet device specifiers (en0 etc). Using the apple-supplied plist to start pf will have the exact same problem that my own plist does.

Comment: It actually does - Apple *included* a plist to load it properly avoiding these issues.

Comment: There is nothing in apples plist that will trigger it to run at any different time vs any other RunAtLoad plist.

Comment: You don't know that, except that it gets executed at the correct time.  I'm telling you how this should be enabled and if you can find an error in anything that I've posted, I'm happy to entertain it.

Comment: How can you say I don't know that when you just posted the plist in your answer. You do have an error in your post, you claim that apple's pf plist does things that it does not do. Also your answer does not address the actual question this post is about.

Answer (score -2):

Read this article about DDoS attacks maybe it will help to you

https://journalofcyberpolicy.com/2020/10/02/33-types-of-ddos-attacks-dissected/